# Add 10 to a value in large xml file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have in a large xml file some hundred svg graphs where I want to change the

```
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 88.74)">
```

88.74 to 98.74 i.e to add 10 to every line that starts with

```
<svg:g transform="matrix(
```

How can one achieve this task without much handwork? I know of substitutions, but additions have escaped my attention.

Comment: Use a scripting language like Perl, PHP, Python, et. cet.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/<svg:g transform="matrix\(.*?\K[\d.]+(?=\))/$&+10/ge' file.xml`

Comment: Add 10 where in the line ?Just the last value ?IS every line the same format and length ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what features of your example we can depend on. Will there always be the same number of fields (words) on each line? Will you always want to modify only the last number of each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[ ")>]' '/\<svg\:g transform\=\"matrix\(/ {sub($(NF-3), 10+$(NF-3))}1' infile > outfile
```

`awk` command with `-F` option define space ,`"`,`)` and `>` as field separators. then search for line that contains pattern `<svg:g transform="matrix(`. next pickup field `$(NF-3)` and replace it with 10 value added to that.

`$(NF)` -> last `>` , `$(NF-1)` -> is last `"` , `$(NF-2)` -> is last `)` and finally `$(NF-3)` -> is my desired value that wants to add +10 value.

```
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06  88.74    )        "      >
                                       $(NF-3) $(NF-2) $(NF-1) $(NF)
```

Input:

```
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 4.74)">
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 88.74)">
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 5.74)">
```

Output:

```
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 14.74)">
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 98.74)">
<svg:g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.06 15.74)">
```

Comment: You miss many spaces in output - `print $0` is separate all fields by spaces if you didn't order other `OFS`, so `awk -F"[ \)]" '/\<svg\:g transform\=\"matrix\(/{$(NF-1)+=10;$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) ")" $NF; $NF=""}1` is little be more correct.

Comment: @Costas what do you mean? I checked but I didn't see where I miss spaces. Can you please give me an example where I'm missing spaces.

Comment: Sorry, I miss your choice of `sub`. For undocumented reason when `sub` is used the `IFS` do not substitute by `OFS`.